# How to stub object's property, not method?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, proxyquire

I have a file config.js with the below code in it:

```
module.exports:
{
   development: {
        switch: false
        }
}
```

I have another file bus.js with the below code in it:

```
var config=require('config.js');

getBusiness:function(req,callback){
         if(config.switch) {
                  // Do something
         }else{
                 // Do something else
         }
}
```

Now, I want to unit test the file bus.js

```
require('mocha');

var chai = require('chai'),
      expect = chai.expect,
      proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

var bus = proxyquire('bus.js', {
                 'config':{
                        switch:true
                  }
});

describe('Unit Test', function() {

        it('should stub the config.switch', function(done) {
            bus.getBusiness(req, function(data) {
              // It should stub the config.switch with true not false and give code coverage for if-else statmt. 
            });
           done();
        });
});
```

Any Suggestions or help...

Comment: So...it doesn't work? (If you fix the quotes typo.) What happens? Any errors?

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder When I console.log(config.switch) in the test, it gives me null or undefined.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The test case gives me code coverage of else part of bus.js.

Comment: Also `console.log(config.switch)` should be undefined. Try `console.log(config.development.switch)`.. it should be false.

Comment: Is the `"Unit Test'` bug actually in your real code or just a typo here?

Comment: @slebetman it was just a typing mistake and have edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to require your module like this `var config=require('./config.js');`.

Edit: You should change your require call to the above. Even if it works when you proxy as ('config.js') it won't work in real life. Also you probably need to call bus the same way and build the config object as it is in the actual file.

```
var bus = proxyquire('./bus.js', {
             './config':{
                 development: {                   
                    switch:true
                 }
              }
});
```

Comment: I have called 'config' module in my test file. But, is there any way I can override the original config's property value with whatever value I assign to it and use it for testing on the fly?

Comment: I am not able to supply the value.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you can do this in your test file:

```
var chai   = require('chai'),
  expect   = chai.expect;
var config = require('./config');

describe('Unit Test', function() {

  it('should stub the config.switch', function(done) {
    config.development.switch = true;
    bus.getBusiness(req, function(data) {
      ...
      done();
    });
  });

});
```